# How to sort dictionaries objects at the list for comparing these lists in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newcomer in python. Give me please an advice.
I have two lists of JSON's object.

```
list1 = [{"A":"A1"},{"B":"B1"}]
list2 = [{"B":"B1"}, {"A":"A1"}]
```

I need to compare these lists at my test:

I try to do this with `assert`:

```
assert list1 == list2
```

But I got the following:

> E       AssertionError:
>
> ```
> assert [{'A': 'A1'}, {'B', 'B1'}] == [{'B', 'B1'}, {'A': 'A1'}]
> ```
>
> E         At index 0 diff: `{'A': 'A1'} != {'B', 'B1'}`

How can I sort lists of objects before comparing these lists?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Maybe you should try sorting the list first before doing your assert? You can see the assert compares the first element of each list and it fails i.e `{'A': 'A1'} != {'B', 'B1'}`

Comment: Those are not lists of JSON objects, but of a mix of dicts and sets. JSON is a text format.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I made a mistake. The correct lists are |:

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I made a mistake. The correct lists are: list1 = [{"A":"A1"},{"B":"B1"}]
list2 = [{"B":"B1"}, {"A":"A1"}]. So, I need to sort my lists of dictionaries before. After sorting I should get list1 = [{"A":"A1"},{"B":"B1"}]
list2 = [{"A":"A1"},{"B":"B1"}] and then I need to make an "assert".  How  I can sort dictionaries at the list?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. I have found the solution:
            list1 =[{"name":"David","age":"25"},{"name":"John","age":"30"}]
            list2=[{"name":"John","age":"30"},{"name":"David","age":"25"}]

```
        sorted_list1 = sorted(list1, key = lambda item:item["name"])
        sorted_list2 = sorted(list2, key = lambda item:item["name"])
        assert sorted_list1 == sorted_list2
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to compare basic python objects at any depth.
Exclusion is tuple as it immutable

```
def sort_all( obj, nochange = False):
  if nochange:
    obj = obj.copy()

  def _key(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
      sort_all(obj)
      return str({k: obj[k] for k in sorted(obj, key = _key)})
    if isinstance(obj, list):
      sort_all(obj)
    return str(obj)

  if isinstance(obj, dict):
    for k, v in obj.items():
      sort_all(v)
  if isinstance(obj, list):
    obj.sort(key = _key)
  return obj
```

this function sort all lists inside the object so the comparison become simple like that

```
l1 = [{1: 2}, {34: 5, 1: 2}, {2: 3, 'asd': [1, 3, 6, {'b': 55}]}, {4: 3, 'a': {34: 5, 1: 2}}]
l2 = [{2: 3, 'asd': [1, 3, 6, {'b': 55}]}, {4: 3, 'a': {1: 2, 34: 5}}, {1: 2}, {1: 2, 34: 5}]
l1 == l2
False
sort_all(l1)
[{34: 5, 1: 2}, {1: 2}, {2: 3, 'asd': [1, 3, 6, {'b': 55}]}, {4: 3, 'a': {34: 5, 1: 2}}]
sort_all(l2)
[{1: 2, 34: 5}, {1: 2}, {2: 3, 'asd': [1, 3, 6, {'b': 55}]}, {4: 3, 'a': {1: 2, 34: 5}}]
l1 == l2
True
```

or simply

```
sort_all(l1) == sort_all(l2)
```

by default function changes the object passed, if you want to avoid this, use nochange = True

```
l1 = [{1: 2}, {34: 5, 1: 2}, {2: 3, 'asd': [1, 3, 6, {'b': 55}]}, {4: 3, 'a': {34: 5, 1: 2}}]
l2 = [{2: 3, 'asd': [1, 3, 6, {'b': 55}]}, {4: 3, 'a': {1: 2, 34: 5}}, {1: 2}, {1: 2, 34: 5}]
sort_all(l1,nochange=True) == sort_all(l2,nochange=True)
True
l1 == l2
False
```

You can also compare class instances this way if they have **str** and **eq** methods implemented. For example

```
class CTest():
  def __init__(self, param):
    self.attr = param
  def __str__(self):
    return f"CTest_<{self.attr}>"
  def __eq__(self, obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, CTest):
      return False
    return self.attr == obj.attr

l1 = [CTest(1234),{1: 2}, {34: 5, 1: 2}, {2: 3, 'asd': [1, 3, 6, {'b': 55}, CTest(1),]}, {4: 3, 'a': {34: 5, 1: 2}}]
l2 = [{2: 3, 'asd': [1, 3, 6, CTest(1), {'b': 55}]}, {4: 3, 'a': {1: 2, 34: 5}}, {1: 2}, {1: 2, 34: 5},CTest(1234)]

l1 == l2
False

sort_all(l1) == sort_all(l2)
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much